# Cython : TypeError: 'list' does not have the buffer interface with list of int

Tags: python, cython

I get the error - *TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface*   -when trying to run the following code using Cython :

```
cdef int[:] lista = range(1000)
```

I'm new with Cython. It seems rather simple to me but I don't know why it is not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists aren't guaranteed to have all their entries being of the same type, therefore their memory isn't arranged as an array of C integers, which is what your memoryview expects.

The [Python array library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) should be compatible:

```
cdef int[:] lista = array.array('i',range(1000))
```

The easiest option though is probably to use a numpy array. The [`arange` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) gives you an integer range:

```
cdef int[:] lista = numpy.arange(1000,dtype=numpy.int32)
```

---

A few notes on data types: the type of the array and the type specified in Cython need to match. On my PC the `array` code works as written and the `numpy` code needs `int32` to match with `cdef int[:]` and `int64` (or unspecified_ to match with `cdef long[:]`. The best thing is to specify the data type exactly for both parts.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it does not work. It returns me the following error :

TypeError: 'array.array' does not have the buffer interface

Comment: That code is working but only for long type ; cdef long[:] lista = numpy.arange(1000). So I guess that the problem is indeed the list structure. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think it's a bit platform dependent which types match (slightly unfortunately). You could probably also do `numpy.arange(1000,dtype=numpy.int32)` and I think it would match `int`. Anyway - glad you got it working...